# Getting different device id of one device from gcm

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, devicetoken

I am working on Push notification,i have registered my application in google console. when i fetch device id, it returns different device id everytime in onRegistration() of GCMIntentService class.Please Help me regarding this.

```
@Override protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId)
 { 
   Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);     
   SavePreferences(registrationId,context);
   //Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name); 
  //ServerUtilities.register(context, MainActivity.name, MainActivity.email, registrationId); 
}
```

Comment: Don't know what your query is, but you should call the methods for getting the registration id just once

Comment: I am calling this function one time only. But when i uninstall the app and again install the same then it returns with different device id.                                                         @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        SavePreferences(registrationId,context);
        //Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);
        //ServerUtilities.register(context, MainActivity.name, MainActivity.email, registrationId);
    }

Answer (score 0):

It is a normal situation. You should NOT register device continuously. Register and save `deviceId` to somewhere (e.g. SharedPreferences) and the next time check if you have `deviceId` on SharedPreferences.

I think it's better for you to follow the article: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

It has everything (almost) you need to.

Comment: I'm getting problem when i re-install the app after uninsatallation. It returns different device id for the same device.

Comment: It is expected behaviour. What do you think is wrong with that?